# How to map a SQL VIEW with JPA entity

Tags: sql, view, openjpa

I have created a entity class as

```
@Entity
@Table(name="updates")
public class E_UpdateView{
     @Id
     ...
}
```

I want to map it to a `SQL view "updates`. When server starts up for the first time the the sql view will be created executing the query

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW updates AS  ........
```

But I got an exception as

```
 org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: 
 ERROR: "updates" is not a view
```

I using `OpenJpa1.0` version and `postgresql`.

I think the entity `E_UpdateView` is created by the `JPA` first before executing the query to create the view. Is there any otherwy to achieve this? Will the same type of exception come if the `SQL view` is created first and `JPA` creates the entity?

Comment: By formatting your code it helps everyone viewing your question to understand which part is your code, your error & what you are stuck with.

Comment: Can anybody help me  on this?